# ArcMotion moves view linearly

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am using the following code to move a view when it is clicked by the user with a curved motion:

R.transition.mytranstion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<changeBounds xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <arcMotion android:maximumAngle="90" android:minimumHorizontalAngle="45" android:minimumVerticalAngle="45"/>
</changeBounds>
```

Then I inflate the transition in code and apply it to the view clicked, but the view moves abruptly and linearly rather than in a curve.

```
                ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
                Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(mContext).inflateTransition(R.transition.arc_motion);
                transition.setDuration(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mGridView, transition);
                img.setTranslationX(400);
                img.setTranslationY(800);
                Snackbar.make(mRoot, R.string.arc_motion, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Tried defining ArcMotion and ChangeBounds on the fly rather than inflating from resource, but the result is the same. Also, setting an interpolator on the transition or giving it different durations make no difference. What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you try both minimumHorizontalAngle and minimumVerticalAngle as 0?

Comment: @cyanide makes no difference